# Prove that $ AB = BA $ if and only if $ \det\begin{bmatrix} b & a - c \\ e & d - f \\ \end{bmatrix} = 0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question:**
Let $\mathbb{F}$ a commutative field and $ a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb{F} $ be scalars and suppose that $ A $ and $ B $ are the following matrices: 
$$ A =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & c \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ and
$$ B =
\begin{bmatrix}
d & e \\
0 & f \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Prove that $ AB = BA $ if and only if 
$ \det\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
b & a - c \\
e & d - f \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
= 0 $

My steps: 
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
b & a - c \\
e & d - f \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
= 0 $$
$$ b(d - f) - e(a - c) = 0 $$
$$ bd - bf - ea + ec = 0 $$
$$ bd - bf = ea - ec $$
At this point I considered that one of the following things must be true for the solution to hold:
$$ b = e = 0 $$
which would mean that $ A $ and $ B $ are diagonal matrices meaning $ AB = BA $

Another condition for the solution to hold would be
$$ b = e, a = d, f = c $$
which would mean that $ A = B $ hence $ AB = BA $ must be true.

Would this be the right approach to the problem or is there a point that I am missing?

Comment: "At this point I considered..." at this point you are making a mistake. It is not about special cases, like diagonal matrices.

Comment: I see! I computed what $ AB $ and $ BA $ were and got that $ ae + bf = bd + ce $ rearranging gave me exactly what the determinant of the other matrix resulted in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$AB=\left(\begin{array}{cc} ad & ae+bf\\ 0 & cf \end{array}\right)$$

$$BA = \left(\begin{array}{cc} da & db+ec\\ 0 & fc \end{array}\right) $$

so, $\ ae+bf=db+bf\ $ iff $\ b(d-f)=e(a-c)$, then

$$ det\left(\left[\begin{array}{cc} b & a-c\\ e & d-f \end{array}\right]\right)=b(d-f)-e(a-c)=0 $$